# When calling get_dimension_key_details for the aws api it is stating "This Key ID is not valid"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

According to the docs, I need to pass the DbiresourceID, for example db-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU1VW2X, as the identifier value. However when I do this am getting the Key id not valid error. When I pass my DbiResourceID as the identifier to a similar command like list_available_resource_dimensions it works as intended. I get similar results when doing this in the aws cli. IS there something I am missing or misunderstanding here?

```
get-dimension-key-details
--service-type <value>
--identifier <value>
--group <value>
--group-identifier <value>

list-available-resource-dimensions
--service-type <value>
--identifier <value>
--metrics <value>
```

--identifier (string)

The ID for a data source from which to gather dimension data. This ID must be immutable and unique within an Amazon Web Services Region. When a DB instance is the data source, specify its DbiResourceId value. For example, specify db-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU1VW2X .

I will include here the examples of what I have tried and there output.

```
try:
    response_one = client.list_available_resource_dimensions(
        ServiceType=service_type,
        Identifier=identifier,
        Metrics=metrics
    )
    print(response_one)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e.response_one['Error']['Message']}")
```

Output:

```
{'MetricDimensions': [{'Metric': 'db.load', 'Groups': [{'Group': 'db.wait_event_type',      'Dimensions': [{'Identifier': 'db.wait_event_type.name'}]}, {'Group': 'db.user', 'Dimensions':     [{'Identifier': 'db.user.id'}, {'Identifier': 'db.user.name'}]}, {'Group': 'db.session_type', 'Dimensions': [{'Identifier': 'db.session_type.name'}]}, {'Group': 'db.sql_tokenized', 'Dimensions': [{'Identifier': 'db.sql_tokenized.id'}, {'Identifier': 'db.sql_tokenized.db_id'}, {'Identifier': 'db.sql_tokenized.statement'}]}, {'Group': 'db.wait_event', 'Dimensions': [{'Identifier': 'db.wait_event.name'}, {'Identifier': 'db.wait_event.type'}]}, {'Group': 'db.application', 'Dimensions': [{'Identifier': 'db.application.name'}]}, {'Group': 'db.host', 'Dimensions': [{'Identifier': 'db.host.id'}, {'Identifier': 'db.host.name'}]}, {'Group': 'db.sql', 'Dimensions': [{'Identifier': 'db.sql.id'}, {'Identifier': 'db.sql.db_id'}, {'Identifier': 'db.sql.statement'}, {'Identifier': 'db.sql.tokenized_id'}]}, {'Group': 'db', 'Dimensions': [{'Identifier': 'db.name'}]}]}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Mon, 05 Jun 2023 20:52:04 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '982', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': ''}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

When trying the get_dimension_key_details:

```
try:
    response = client.get_dimension_key_details(
        ServiceType=service_type,
        Identifier=identifier,
        Group=group,
        GroupIdentifier=group_identifier,
        RequestedDimensions=requested_dimensions
    )
    print(response)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e.response['Error']['Message']}")
```

Output: An error occurred: This Key ID is not valid.

What should be returned is query text.